# Why do I use lambda expressions instead of functions?

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-6.0

I have a really simple question.

I wanted to try async programming and since I could not wrap my head around lambda expressions I decided to start there.

Why would you use for example this:

```
bool IsLonger(int x, string y) => y.Length > x;
```

**over this:**

```
private bool IsLonger(int x, string y)
{
    return y.Length > x ? true:false;
}
```

**if you can't use:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Return positive if inteager is higher number than string length
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">X is our inteager</param>
/// <param name="y">Y is our string</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

With lambda expressions.
Therefore it's not much usefull if you work in team?

I'd like to have some opinions, maybe I approach this the wrong way.
Thanks!

Comment: that isn't actually a "lambda expression" - it is an ["expression-bodied member"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), but the answer would be "brevity" - they are identical, but many folks find the terse version more convenient for trivial methods / properties; personally, I like that it allows me to see more of such members at once - it reduces the cognitive load of having to scroll to see more members

Comment: Why do you think you cannot put a comment on top of your function in the first scenario?

Comment: @MarcGravell expression bodied method.

Comment: @MarcGravell method is used too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods

Comment: This is an expression-bodied method, which is one example of the more general feature of expression-bodied members :)

Comment: side note: if you ever find yourself writing `? true : false` - stop, delete 14 characters, and continue :) (unless there's a custom `true()` operator overload, blah blah blah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I want to correct this:

> use lambda expressions instead of functions

What you are showing in your example, as Daniel has pointed out in his answer, is just [an expression bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

The use of an expression bodied over a method is not a standard, but more of a feature that is supported by the C# language, so it is up to you when you want to use it and when not.

I would always use expression bodied members instead of methods, for short methods bodies that fit the monitor, but this is going to a primary opinion based answer.

Secondly, for the `return y.Length > x ? true:false;` section, I will expand this with an example. If you hold the value of the `y.Length > x` into a variable, it would look like this:

```
bool condition = y.Length > x;
```

and then the return would look like this:

```
return condition ? true : false;
```

Now you will see that it is more intuitive to return directly the condition.

```
return condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a lambda. That is an expression-bodied method/member. It is just a shorthand for the other.

Comment: "Lambdas create hidden classes and are allocated on the stack" - neither is actually necessarily the case, note - it depends on what happens with it

Comment: "Lambdas create hidden classes and are allocated on the stack" is a pretty dubious statement. I'm not entirely sure what's intended here, but I doubt that it's a useful sentence.